# Ajax Return Response HTML code instead Data (LARAVEL 8)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel-8

I already try this code

```
<script>
$('#test').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            url : '/getRequest',
            type : 'GET',
            success: function(response) {       
            alert(response)                 
            },
            error: function(response){console.log(response); }
            
         });
<script>

<button id="test" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">test</button>

MY ROUTE

   Route::get('/getRequest', function(){
                    return "blablabla";
            });
```

terminal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76gnj.png)

I just Want to get blablabla inside my alert

Comment: Can you check the whole HTML from response? Probably there is en error on backend

Comment: no error occur when i double check my back end

Comment: Attach this html to question, please